# I can't run/debug Azure Function project in VS2017 using Windows 10 Enterprise

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

Whenever i try to run/debug an Azure Function project in Visual Studio 2017 i get an error stating that i need .Net Framework 4.7.1 (which i can't install due to have preinstalled windows 10 Enterprise in my working machine by company policy),I'm using Azure Functions and Web Tools Extension version 15.0.40608.0, anyone can help me with a workaround on this matter ?

Comment: What is your question? You already have the solution in your question. I'm guessing there's no workaround for that, since it's needed to run your Functions.

Comment: i can run the functions using Functions CLI so i guess its a pure VS2017 extension dependency with that specific version

Answer (score 0):

If you got exactly this error message

> The reference assemblies for framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. ...

You can try to change your target framework to a version you have installed, like the error suggests.

Right click on your project, Edit FunctionProjectName.csproj, find `<TargetFramework>net471</TargetFramework>`, change it to the version installed, like `net461`.

If you can't run this project correctly on lower version of .Net Framework, as rickvdbosch says, it might be required to update your Windows and install the SDK or modify your code to make it compatible on lower version.